# Match file names and not substrings in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a list of file names using a regex. Instead of matching *just* the full name, it is matching both the name and a substring of the name.

Three example files are

```
t0 = r"1997_06_daily.txt"
t1 = r"2010_12_monthly.txt"
t2 = r"2018_01_daily_images.txt"
```

I am using the regex `d`.

```
a = r"[0-9]{4}"
b = r"_[0-9]{2}_"
c = r"(daily|daily_images|monthly)"
d = r"(" + a + b + c + r".txt)"
```

when I run

```
t0 = r"1997_06_daily.txt"
t1 = r"2010_12_monthly.txt"
t2 = r"2018_01_daily_images.txt"

a = r"[0-9]{4}"
b = r"_[0-9]{2}_"
c = r"(daily|daily_images|monthly)"
d = r"(" + a + b + c + r".txt)"

for t in (t0, t1, t2):
    m = re.match(d, t)
    if m is not None:
        print(t, m.groups(), sep="\n", end="\n\n")
```

I get

```
1997_06_daily.txt
("1997_06_daily.txt", "daily")

2010_12_monthly.txt
("2010_12_monthly.txt", "monthly")

2018_01_daily_images.txt
("2018_01_daily_images.txt", "daily_images")
```

How can I force the regex to only return the version that includes the **full file name** and **not the substring**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your `c` pattern non-capturing with `'?:'`

```
c = r"(?:daily|daily_images|monthly)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working correctly. The issue you are seeing is how groups work in regex. Your regex `c` is in parentheses. Parentheses in regex signify that this match should be treated as a group. By printing `m.group()`, you are printing a tuple of all the groups that matched. Luckily, the first element in the group is always the full match, so just use the following:

```
print(t, m.groups()[0], sep="\n", end="\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're only looking for regex solutions but you could easily use os module to split the extension and return index 0. Otherwise, as Bill S. stated, `m.groups()[0]` returns the 0th index of the regex group.

```
# os solution
import os

s = "1997_06_daily.txt"

os.path.splitext(s)[0]
```